# Removing named properties from "decorated" array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Although my question stems from DataTables.net, I imagine it is applicable elsewhere:

I retrieve an array-like object from a DataTables-created table like this:

```
var data = tableInstance.data(); // tableInstance is already a DataTables table instance
```

But the data, while array-like, is actually an object decorated with the DataTables API, resulting in an "array" that looks something like this (reduced to a fake "brief" version):

```
[
  0: {thing: "stuff"}, 
  1: {thing: "nextStuff"}, 
  $: function(){}, 
  button: function() {},
  length: 2
]
```

I would like to isolate just the actual array. Does anybody spot an elegant way of doing this? The "obvious" way is to just iterate X times, up to data.length. For example, using an "each" iterator, which inherently does just that:

```
var newData = [];

data.each(function (el, index) {
  newData.push(el);
})
```

But I can't help wondering if there's a better way. Generating the new array (or editing in-place... no requirement for it to be new) by removing unwanted properties, rather than by pushing wanted items into a new array.

Or is this just too much of a micro-optimization (even with tens of thousands of items) to even bother with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a better way. Use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```
const newData = Array.from(data)
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks for this. I idly wonder what the performance difference is (suspecting the from is faster), but at my scale, it would be purely academic.

Comment: Yup Array.from being fastest would be my guess but I'd love to know for sure if you feel like testing it out :)

Comment: Not sure if the test is flawed (and I'm not sure how to replicate DataTables' peculiar array-like object, though I don't think it matters), but .from seems to be highly more performant: https://jsperf.com/stripping-array-decoration-iterator-vs-array-from/1